# How prove this inequality $\sum_{k=2}^{49}\frac{1}{k^2}\ge\frac{9}{10}\ln{2}$?

Tags: inequality

show that
$$\sum_{k=2}^{49}\dfrac{1}{k^2}\ge\dfrac{9}{10}\ln{2}$$

my idea: since
$$\dfrac{1}{k^2}\ge\dfrac{1}{k(k+1)}=\dfrac{1}{k}-\dfrac{1}{k+1}$$
so
$$\sum_{k=2}^{49}\dfrac{1}{k^2}\ge\sum_{k=2}^{49}\left(\dfrac{1}{k}-\dfrac{1}{k+1}\right)=\dfrac{1}{2}-\dfrac{1}{50}=\dfrac{12}{25}$$ 
But $$\dfrac{9}{10}\ln{2}>\dfrac{12}{25}$$

other idea:
$$\dfrac{1}{k^2}\ge\dfrac{3}{(2k-1)(2k+1)}$$

so How prove it? Thank you

and I found the constant $\dfrac{9}{10}\ln{2}$ is best value.can see

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28%5Csum_%7Bk%3D2%7D%5E%7B49%7D%5Cdfrac%7B1%7D%7Bk%5E2%7D%29-%289%2F10%29*ln2&dataset=

[image]

I Looking forward to answer this problem by hand! Thank you

Comment: the difference is around 0.001, so it may be hard ot find a non numerical method.

Comment: maybe this problem exsit to find solve by hand.

Comment: You must obviously employ the fact that $\displaystyle\sum_1^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}n=\ln2$. Just not sure how.

Answer (score 3):

$$\sum_{k=2}^{49} \dfrac{1}{k^2} = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \dfrac{1}{k^2} - 1 - \sum_{k=50}^\infty \dfrac{1}{k^2} = \dfrac{\pi^2}{6} - 1 - \sum_{k=50}^\infty \dfrac{1}{k^2}$$.

The function $f(x) = 1/x^2$ is strictly decreasing on $[49, +\infty)$ so the right hand Riemann sum $\sum_{k=50}^\infty \dfrac{1}{k^2}$ is less than $\int_{49}^\infty \dfrac{1}{x^2}\, dx$. The latter is equal to $1/49$. Therefore,
$$\dfrac{\pi^2}{6} - 1 - \sum_{k=50}^\infty \dfrac{1}{k^2} > \dfrac{\pi^2}{6} - 1 - \dfrac{1}{49}$$
which one can check is numerically bigger than $\dfrac{9}{10} \log(2)$ by about $0.00069344$. This is not a direct estimate but perhaps of some help.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is a finite sum over reasonably many simple terms: one can always [compute the difference explicitly](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum%5B1%2Fk%5E2%2C+%7Bk%2C2%2C49%7D%5D+-+9%2F10+Ln%5B2%5D) and get that it is roughly $9\cdot 10^{-4} > 0$.